# Conditional type check for undefined

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types

For the code

```
type stringUndefined = "string" | undefined;

type What<T> = T extends undefined ? "true" : "false";

const no : What<stringUndefined> = "";
```

no becomes `"true" | "false"` instead of what I would expect, `"true"`

[TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&pretty=true&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1&downlevelIteration=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOBLAdgcwKrICYQGYoiygF4oAiOJNMqAHygFds8CsBuAKA9EigHUAFgENgAHgAqAPhJRxUCAA9gEbDEbN8yQlAD85BAwg0AXOVxCANjCOcOUAMYB7ZHCjJHUU4JGjKKDBqs0qRkZJxAA)

[image: Code]

Edit:

strict null checks are enabled

Comment: Use `undefined extends T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"string" | undefined` doesn't extend `undefined`, because it can be `"string"`.

But `undefined` extends `"string" | undefined`, because the members of a union extend (refine) the union. So:

```
type StringLiteralOrUndefined = "string" | undefined;

type What<T> = undefined extends T ? true : false;

type X = What<StringLiteralOrUndefined>;
//   ^? type X = true

type UnrelatedType = string | number;

type Y = What<UnrelatedType>;
//   ^? type Y = false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?downlevelIteration=true&target=99&pretty=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwDKOBeBDANgPLwCqyAJhAGYoTlQC8UARAM4IqrNQA+UArhWq1yAbgBQ40JCgB1ABa5gAHgAqAPkYChNZHSgQAHtgqsoqqAH4oCftABcUKgVYQJU8NAAaWhUuVwSGiY2HhEpDoi6hIA9DFQCQB6lpLS0GTwEPhKdKqeWuxBqLxQyPwAtgBGOO5pUACavooqGVk55HmQ0eJxCVDJ4kA)